# how to format the data which does not have any escape character in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have below structure of election booth data, my task is count those name present in data and choose the winner which has got high voting.

> booth data1 -
>   jojojujujijijajajejejojojujijijajajejejojojujujajajijijeje
>
> booth data2 - 
>   jojojujujijijajajejejojojujijijajajejejojojujujajajijijeje
>
> booth data3 - 
>   jojojujujijijajajejejojojujijijajajejejojojujujajajijijeje

I have to calculate the votes based on names given in above file and find the largest count using spark.

May I know how should I format the data?

Comment: do you have the list of all the possible names or something like that ?

Comment: no my assumption is jojo , juju, jiji,jaja, jeje are names, in this case how would i split the data according to the names what i have given above?

Comment: So all names are 4 characters?

Comment: The names either need to be of similar length or of a valid regex type or delimited by some character. You're raising the bar too high. This is SO not hackathon :D